# Change 2 images to one text onClick

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When a user clicks on either thumbs_up or thumbs_down, those 2 icons should be **replaced** with a text like 'You voted'. How do I do that?

```
   <div class="thumbsup">
       <%= link_to image_tag('othericons/thumbsup_off.PNG', height: '20', width: '20', like_post_comment_path(comment.post_id, comment), method: :put, :remote => true %>
   </div>

    <div class="thumbsdown">
        <%= link_to image_tag('othericons/thumbsdown_off.PNG', height: '20', width: '20', dislike_post_comment_path(comment.post_id, comment), method: :put, :remote => true %>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'd look into using jQuery append maybe? and just append a div or text positioned over the image?

Answer (score 1):

Add this in an asset file

```
$('.thumbsdown a, .thumbsup a').on('click', function() {
  $('.thumbsdown').before('You voted')
  $('.thumbsdown, .thumbsup').remove()
})
```

What this does is add the text `You voted` before the `thumbsdown` div and then remove the div afterwards.  There's no single right way to do this so it's up to you how.